# Python code for filtering against order dates is not behaving properly

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, filter

I have written a while loop to filter through a database of orders so that only orders made between two dates selected by the user are appended to an orderDates array and an array for orders to be plotted on a map. I have converted the dates selected by users (these are submitted via an HTML form) into python datetime objects using the following code:

```
filters.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(request.forms.get('startDate')), "%Y-%m-%d"))
filters.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(request.forms.get('endDate')), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

As you can see, the two dates are then added to an array called filters. My problem then comes when I'm checking against each of the orders, for some reason even though I am selecting a date range that should return a number of orders, all orders are being filtered out. Here is the while loop that I wrote:

```
while(x < len(orders)):
    # Checks that postcode is valid
    if(re.search('^(GIR ?0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y])?)|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$',orders[x][15].strip())):
        # Converts the order date into a time object
        orderDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(orders[x][2], "%d/%m/%y")
        print(orderDate)
        # Compares the order date with the start date and end date of the timeframe to ensure it lies between them
        if(orderDate > filters[0]) and (orderDate < filters[1]):
            # If the order was made during the timeframe requested and it fits the order category requested then it is added to mapOrders
            if(filters[4] == "All"):
                mapOrders.append(orders[x])
                orderDates.append(orderDate)
                print("Order added")
            elif(orders[x][21].strip() == filters[4]):
                mapOrders.append(orders[x])
                orderDates.append(orderDate)
                print("Order added")
            else:
                print("Order filtered out")
        else:
            print("Order filtered out")
            print(filters[0])
            print(filters[1])
    else:
        print(orders[x][15])
        print("Order filtered out,regex.")

    x = x + 1
```

Here is some console output produced whilst the program is running through this while loop, the 2 dates chosen by the user were the 1st of May 2015 for the start date and the 1st of July 2015 for the end date:

```
2015-05-14 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-14 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-16 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-16 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-16 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-12 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-12 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-07 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-07 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-07 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-08 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-09 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-04 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-04 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-05 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-05 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-05 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-05-01 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-05-01 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
2015-05-03 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
Order filtered out
2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-07-01 00:00:00
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: From your output I can tell you that `filters[0]` is actually `2015-05-01 00:00:00` (first of May), not the 1st of June

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I meant to say, it still doesn't explain what's going wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, there was a space in filters[4] that shouldn't have been there.